# Python: Remove empty folders recursively

Tags: python

I'm having troubles finding and deleting empty folders with my Python script. 
I have some directories with files more or less like this:

```
A/
--B/
----a.txt
----b.pdf
--C/
----d.pdf
```

I'm trying to delete all files which aren't PDFs and after that delete all empty folders. I can delete the files that I want to, but then I can't get the empty directories. What I'm doing wrong?

```
    os.chdir(path+"/"+name+"/Test Data/Checklists")
    pprint("Current path: "+ os.getcwd())
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path+"/"+name+"/Test Data/Checklists"):
            for name in files:
                    if not(name.endswith(".pdf")):
                            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    pprint("Deletting empty folders..")
    pprint("Current path: "+ os.getcwd())
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path+"/"+name+"/Test Data/Checklists", topdown=False):
            if not dirs and not files:
                    os.rmdir(root)
```

Comment: Just throwing out a guess here: What happens if you at the last line, instead of trying to remove root, append it to a list, and then after all the looping, remove all the directories of that list?

Comment: Maybe not related to the problem, but better use `os.path.join` to form the paths (eg. within `os.walk` calls).

Answer (score 6):

use insted the function

```
os.removedirs(path)
```

this will remove directories until the parent directory is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should remove the directories immediately after deleting the files, rather than doing two passes with `os.walk`

```
import sys
import os

for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if not(name.endswith(".pdf")):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, name))

    # check whether the directory is now empty after deletions, and if so, remove it
    if len(os.listdir(dir)) == 0:
        os.rmdir(dir)
```

Comment: This does not work because empty folder may contain an empty folder inside which will return `len(os.listdir(dir))`as 1 and it won't delete the empty folders

Comment: Since `topdown=False` any lower level (especially leaf node) empty directories would have been removed by the second stanza already, since they would be processed first as `dir`

Answer (score 0):

For empty folders deletion you can use this snippet. 
It can be combined with some files deletion, but as last run should be used as is.

```
import os


def drop_empty_folders(directory):
    """Verify that every empty folder removed in local storage."""

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
        if not dirnames and not filenames:
            os.rmdir(dirpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all empty folders

```
import os 
folders = './A/'  # directory
for folder in list(os.walk(folders)) :
    if not os.listdir(folder[0]):
        os.removedirs(folder[0])
```